# Libgdx internationalization

Tags: internationalization, libgdx

I wonder where do I put my Bundle file for internationalization. The Libgdx wiki doesn't explain where (Android assets folder?) and they use as example the name of file called MyBundle. May I use another name? My apologize for my naivety.

Answer (score 3):

First argument of I18NBundle constructor is a FileHandle instance. That's mean that you are not limited by one specific folder. See [this wiki entry](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) on file handling in libGDX. I suppose you use sample from official wiki and it has this line:

```
FileHandle baseFileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle");
```

In this particular case, when we use `Gdx.files.internal`, bundle must be located in Android project's `assets` folder. There is no restrictions on file name also.

Comment: Let me see if I get it: when I use the command Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle") the program will know the file will be at the assets folder and load for me?

Comment: @César `Gdx.files.internal` gives you a `FileHandle`, relative to the android assets folder. That means, in your case inside the assets it looks for a folder named "i18n", which contains the `File` "MyBundle".

Comment: It show now: "Can't find bundle for base file handle i18n/MyBundle, locale pt_BR". What can be?

Answer (score 1):

Create i18n folder in assets of android module. create different properties files in i18n folder like lang.properties, lang_es.properties, lang_fr.properties etc.

Then I use this code in my project.

```
FileHandle internal = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/lang"); 
I18NBundle local = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, Locale.ROOT); 
I18NBundle portuguese = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, new Locale("pt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the default local :

```
    FileHandle internal = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle");
    I18NBundle local = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to use the phone locals :
Create an i18n in assets folder and a subfolder (example MyBundle).
Insite this folder put files :
- MyBundle.properties (defaults values, exemple : game=Game)
- MyBundle_en.properties (game=Game)
- MyBundle_fr.properties

Initialization :
        FileHandle internal = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle");
        I18NBundle local = I18NBundle.createBundle(internal, Locale.getDefault());

Use :
        String sTitre=local.get("game");